# xamarin forms DatePicker Cancel/OK event

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, event-handling, android-datepicker

I found and tried one example of a custom rendered DatePicker, for Android, for Xamarin Forms and does not show which button was clicked in UnFocus. At least not for me. Its from stackoverflow. [Xamarin.Forms Android DatePicker/TimePicker button listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009155/xamarin-forms-android-datepicker-timepicker-button-listener?rq=1)

Has the example in this article helped anyone else? I really need to know when the OK button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extends [Nick Kovalsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60786875/199364). I also fixed a bug in that answer, that meant the renderer was never used.

Subclass DatePicker, so that you can add a new BindableProperty and a new method. Place this in your cross-platform project.

OKCancelDatePicker.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

// Replace with YOUR namespace.
namespace TestBugs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// NOTE: Requires custom renderer on each platform.
    /// </summary>
    public class OKCancelDatePicker : DatePicker
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty UserCancelledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(UserCancelled), typeof(bool), typeof(OKCancelDatePicker), false);
        /// <summary>
        /// Bind to "UserCancelled", to propagate this change elsewhere (e.g. to a VM, or to trigger some logic).
        /// </summary>
        public bool UserCancelled {
            get => (bool)GetValue(UserCancelledProperty);
            set => SetValue(UserCancelledProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Optionally add code here. Though usually you'll detect the change by binding to UserCancelled.
        /// </summary>
        public void OnPickerClosed()
        {
            if (UserCancelled) {
                // User cancelled.
                _ = 0;   // Dummy code, to set a breakpoint on. You can remove this.
            } else {
                // User selected OK.
                _ = 0;   // Dummy code, to set a breakpoint on. You can remove this.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create a renderer for Android. Place this in your .Android project.

OKCancelDatePickerRenderer.cs:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
// Replace these with YOUR namespaces.
using TestBugs;   // Contains OKCancelDatePicker.
using TestBugs.Droid;   // Contains OKCancelDatePickerRenderer.

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(OKCancelDatePicker), typeof(OKCancelDatePickerRenderer))]
// Replace this with YOUR Android namespace.
namespace TestBugs.Droid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Based on Nick Kovalsky's https://stackoverflow.com/a/60786875/199364.
    /// </summary>
    public class OKCancelDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        public OKCancelDatePickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            //Disposing
            if (e.OldElement != null) {
                _element = null;
            }

            //Creating
            if (e.NewElement != null) {
                _element = e.NewElement as OKCancelDatePicker;
            }
        }

        protected OKCancelDatePicker _element;

        protected override DatePickerDialog CreateDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day)
        {
            // This mimics what the original renderer did.
            var dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context, (o, e) =>
            {
                _element.Date = e.Date;
                ((IElementController)_element).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
            }, year, month, day);

            // These use our custom actions when buttons pressed.
            dialog.SetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Positive, Context.Resources.GetString(global::Android.Resource.String.Ok), OnOk);
            dialog.SetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative, Context.Resources.GetString(global::Android.Resource.String.Cancel), OnCancel);

            return dialog;
        }

        private void OnCancel(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
        {
            // This is what the original renderer did when Cancel pressed.
            _element.Unfocus();

            // This is our custom logic.
            _element.UserCancelled = true;
            _element?.OnPickerClosed();
        }
        private void OnOk(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
        {
            // This is what the original renderer did when OK pressed.
            _element.Date = ((DatePickerDialog)sender).DatePicker.DateTime;
            _element.Unfocus();

            // This is our custom logic.
            _element.UserCancelled = false;
            _element?.OnPickerClosed();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBugs"
             x:Class="TestBugs.DatePickerTestPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Date Picker Test Page" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <local:OKCancelDatePicker />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

IMPORTANT: If your app runs on other platforms you'll need to do similar on each platform. Per platform, try to find an example to modify. Nick's answer has a link to one for iOS.

---

TBD: I should add here an example of how to bind to that `UserCancelled` property, so you can connect it to logic in your page.

For now, read about [Bindable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties), and google for examples of binding to a `BindableProperty` of a control or view.

Comment: Thanks!! This is what I am looking for.